# why will lines 56 and 67 not work? (.votess +=1;)

Tags: javascript

```
var imgs = ['bmw.jpg', 'bugatti.jpg', 'classic.jpg', 'concept.jpg', 'corvette.jpg', 'dino.jpg', 'lambo.jpg', 'mcclaren.jpg', 'p1.jpg', 'porsche.jpg', 'rally.jpg', 'audi.jpg'];
        // var imgs_count = {'bmw.jpg': 0, 'bugatti.jpg': 0, 'classic.jpg': 0, 'concept.jpg': 0, 'corvette.jpg': 0, 'dino.jpg': 0, 'lambo.jpg': 0, 'mcclaren.jpg': 0, 'p1.jpg': 0, 'porsche.jpg': 0,'rally.jpg': 0, 'audi.jpg':0}

        // for (var i in imgs_count) {
        //   imgs_count[i]
        // }

        var allCars = [];
        var votes;

        function Car(file) {
          this.file = file;
          this.votes = 0;
          allCars.push(this);
        }

        var bmw = new Car('bmw.jpg');
        var bugatti = new Car('bugatti.jpg');
        var classic = new Car('classic.jpg');
        var concept = new Car('concept.jpg');
        var corvette = new Car('corvette.jpg');
        var dino = new Car('dino.jpg');
        var lambo = new Car('lambo.jpg');
        var mcclaren = new Car('mcclaren.jpg');
        var p1 = new Car('p1.jpg');
        var porsche =new Car('porsche.jpg');
        var rally = new Car('rally.jpg');
        var audi = new Car('audi.jpg');

        var idx1 = 0;
        var idx2 = 0;

        var path = 'cars/';
        var done = false;

        function getRandomImage() {
          idx1 = Math.floor(Math.random()*imgs.length);
          var img1 = imgs[idx1];
          idx2 = idx1;
          while (idx2 == idx1) {
            idx2 = Math.floor(Math.random()*imgs.length);
          }
          img2 = imgs[idx2];
          document.getElementById('choice1').setAttribute('src', path + img1);
          document.getElementById('choice2').setAttribute('src', path + img2);

        }

        function setOnClicks(id) {
          document.getElementById(id).addEventListener('click', function(event) {
            var choice = event.target.id;
            if (choice === 'choice1') {
              console.log(allCars);
              var img = document.getElementById(id).getAttribute('src');
              var allCars = img.slice(5,img.length);
              this.allCars[idx1].votes += 1;
              console.log(idx1);
              console.log(this.allCars[idx1].votes)
              if ( allCars[idx1].votes=3) {

                  done = true;

              }
            }
            if (choice === 'choice2') {
              var img = document.getElementById(id).getAttribute('src');
              var allCars = img.slice(5,img.length);
              console.log(idx2);
              console.log(this.allCars[idx2].votes);
              this.allCars[idx2].votes += 1;

              if (allCars[idx2].votes == 3) {
                done = true;
              }
            }
            if (!done)
              getRandomImage();
          });
        }



        getRandomImage();
        setOnClicks('choice1');
        setOnClicks('choice2')l
```

Comment: I cannot get the votes for the array to add +1 when the image is clicked. I get a return of 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '11' of undefined' or something similar, like it cannot find it in my 'allCars' array

Comment: The problem (or at least, _a_ problem) is that `var allCars` and `this.allCars` _are not the same thing_.  See example here:  http://jsfiddle.net/866yocrv/

Comment: if i remove (this) it still shows the same problem

Comment: Even after the first correction there are still a couple of errors in the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're overwriting your global `allCars` with a local `var` declaration of the same name:

```
var allCars = img.slice(5,img.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

you are creating a local variable `allCars` under click event, while `this.allCars` is point to the `allCars` variable under `window` object

```
 var allCars = img.slice(5,img.length);  // this is a local variable
 this.allCars[idx1].votes += 1;   // this is same as window.allCars
 console.log(idx1);
```